# sign in after sign up with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails application that uses Omniauth (twitter signin) with Devise.  After the user clicks "sign up with Twitter" and agrees to the authentication, the application takes them to a devise registration page ( redirect_to new_user_registration_url) where the user has to provide an email. After the user inputs email, it returns to the homepage but the user is not signed in. Therefore, I created a new Devise registrations controller following the instructions here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29  however, i'm still having the same problem. Furthermore, the put statement that I included is not logging in my server records, so I think I've done something wrong.

Can you explain what I might do to get this working?

registrations controller   (note I'm not sure if the code inside after_sign_up_path_for is correct, but the puts statement isn't getting logged for some reason)

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected
  def after_sign_up_path_for(user)
    # puts resource
     puts "checking resource"
    # session[:user_id] = user.id
    sign_in_and_redirect user
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      puts "user persisted"
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      flash.notice = "Signed in!"
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
```

User.rb

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.nickname
    user.image = auth["info"]["image"]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the route for the new controller to override the Devise registrations controller:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations'}
```